# Building micropython in stm32 port in windows

Tags: build, linker, embedded, cross-compiling, micropython

I am currently trying to build a MicroPython application on Windows 10 using the Atollic TrueSTUDIO IDE for a NUCLEO-H743ZI development board.

I get the following error.

```
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/9 2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/libgcc.a
c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools Arm Embedded\9 2019-q4-major\bin\arm-none-eabi-ld.exe: cannot find build-NUCLEO_H743ZI/lib/mbedtls/library/ssl_: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:614: build-NUCLEO_H743ZI/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: Given the name of the missing library(`ssl_`), it looks to me like some environment variable isn't being set so the make variable that's used to compose the SSL library is blank and causing an incomplete library name.

Comment: The problem can be summarized with one word: Eclipse.

Comment: I really hope VS Code overtakes the current industry fetish with eclipse

Answer (score 2):

It was command line length problem. I shortened the length of the command and so I was able to build it. 
[Reference]https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/6031
Thanks for your comments